# Mysql 8.0 not using the correct index causing slow execution compared to Mysql 5.6

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am migrating from mysql 5.6(innodb) to mysql 8.0(innodb).
For one of the query(used for pagination) the execution time for MySql 8 is slower than Mysql 5.6, probably because it's not using the correct index.

Mysql 5.6

```
CREATE TABLE `contest_user_team_mapping` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_match_mapping_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`contest_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`entry_fee_type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`match_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`additional_info` text,
`user_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `contest_user` (`contest_id`,`user_match_mapping_id`),
KEY `idx_contest_id` (`contest_id`),
KEY `idx_updated_at` (`updated_at`),
KEY `idx_user_match_mapping_id` (`user_match_mapping_id`),
KEY `indx_comp` (`contest_id`,`user_match_mapping_id`),
KEY `idx_match_id` (`match_id`),
KEY `idx_user_id` (`user_id`)
)   ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=533924175 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


mysql> explain     select  id, contest_id
    from  contest_user_team_mapping
    where  id >=1
      and  match_id = 1745
    limit  100;

+----+-------------+---------------------------+-------------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                     | type        | possible_keys        | key                  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+---------------------------+-------------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | contest_user_team_mapping | index_merge | PRIMARY,idx_match_id | idx_match_id,PRIMARY | 17,8    | NULL | 4869005 | Using intersect(idx_match_id,PRIMARY); Using where |
+----+-------------+---------------------------+-------------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+------+---------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Mysql 8.0

```
CREATE TABLE `contest_user_team_mapping` (
`id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_match_mapping_id` bigint NOT NULL,
`contest_id` bigint NOT NULL,
`entry_fee_type` int DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`match_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
`additional_info` text,
`user_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `contest_user` (`contest_id`,`user_match_mapping_id`),
 KEY `idx_contest_id` (`contest_id`),
 KEY `idx_updated_at` (`updated_at`),
 KEY `idx_match_id` (`match_id`),
 KEY `idx_user_id` (`user_id`)


mysql> explain   select id, contest_id
    from  contest_user_team_mapping
    where  match_id = 1974
      and  id>=1
    limit  100;

+----+-------------+---------------------------+------------+-------+----------------------+---------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table                     | partitions | type  | possible_keys        | key     | key_len | ref  | rows     | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------------------+------------+-------+----------------------+---------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | contest_user_team_mapping | NULL       | range | PRIMARY,idx_match_id | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL | 97063072 |     0.02 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------------------------+------------+-------+----------------------+---------+---------+------+----------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql>     select  /*+ NO_RANGE_OPTIMIZATION(contest_user_team_mapping) INDEX_MERGE(contest_user_team_mapping)*/
        id,
        contest_id
    from  contest_user_team_mapping FORCE INDEX FOR
    JOIN  (idx_match_id,PRIMARY)
    where  id >=1
      and  match_id = 1974
    limit  1;

+----+-------------+---------------------------+------------+------+----------------------+--------------+---------+-------+-------+----------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table                     | partitions | type | possible_keys        | key          | key_len | ref   | rows  | filtered | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+---------------------------+------------+------+----------------------+--------------+---------+-------+-------+----------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | contest_user_team_mapping | NULL       | ref  | PRIMARY,idx_match_id | idx_match_id | 9       | const | 34566 |    33.33 | Using index condition |
+----+-------------+---------------------------+------------+------+----------------------+--------------+---------+-------+-------+----------+-----------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

For Mysql 8.0 it does not seems to be using the index idx_match_id,PRIMARY which is probably causing it to be slow. I also tried to use force index but that does not seem to help either.

Comment: Dont just use single column indexes "just because".  Indexes should be prepared based on most common types of queries you plan to run.  Make your KEY `idx_match_id` based on (match_id, id).  This way the engine can pre-qualify the MATCH, but ALSO have the ID qualifier as part of the WHERE, otherwise it appears to be fighting itself on which index to use as "best index".  And why ID > 1 (unless a control record?).  And without an ORDER BY basis, the top 100 will just grab the first 100 with no other context of "best" that you may be looking for.

Comment: @DRapp Thx. replacing (match_id) by (match_id, id) indeed made the mysql 8.0 to use that index. Thx. Although it still used range optimisation instead of index_merge, performance was almost similar.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
KEY `idx_match_id` (`match_id`),
```

with

```
INDEX(match_id, id, contest_id)
```

That would be "covering" and is likely to be "correctly" picked in both 5.6 and 8.0.

Comment: Hi rick. Thx for your suggestion. i tried. i tried INDEX(match_id, id) and it works fine. Can you explain why did you include contest_id here? as for the query i mentioned  contest_id is not part of where clause. i do have some queries which have contest_id in where clause exclusively.

Comment: @SulabhKumar - A "covering index" contains _all_ the columns needed _anywhere_ in the Select.  This leads to some speedup.  That's why I added `contest_id`.  It may be that _this_ Select does not benefit much from having a covering index instead of one that just handles the `WHERE`.

Answer (score 0):

Add match_ id，contest_ ID union index